# How to minify my personal jquery frontend microframework

Tags: javascript, import, minify

I've made my personal jQuery microframework with useful utilities. It has a directory structure like this:

```
/jspocket
  - jspocket.js
  /scripts
    - include.js
    - navigation.js
    - slider.js
    - popups.js
    ...
```

Therefore it is imported into html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspocket/jspocket.js"></script>
```

In `jspocket.js` is this code for importing all the .js files from '/script' directory into an html file:

```
$.getScript(jspocket_dir + "/scripts/navigation.js");
$.getScript(jspocket_dir + "/scripts/popups.js");
$.getScript(jspocket_dir + "/scripts/slider.js");
$.getScript(jspocket_dir + "/scripts/include.js");
...
```

---

Now I would like to create a minified version of my framework so there will be only one file `jspocket.min.js`. But the problem is that the commands like:

`$.getScript(jspocket_dir + "/scripts/navigation.js");`

will not work, simply becouse `scripts/navigation.js` does not exist in minified version, it should be all in one file.

So the question is how could I minify the framework into one file (without manually copying all the code into one file)? Should I change the way scripts are imported? Does the new import/export features of JS solve it somehow? How is this problem solved in general? I'm using node.js and npm, so maybe there could be a good packages for this?

Comment: why do you need the `$.getScript` ?! what is the purpose of it?

Comment: It was just the way of dividing the functionality into multiple files without importing them all manually into .html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a build system to minify the files into one file but leave `jspocket.js` out of the process.

There are many build systems out there like [GruntJs](https://gruntjs.com/) , [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/)

This following is how to do it in Gulp

```
// the plugins
var gulp = require('gulp')
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

// task
gulp.task('minify-js', function () {
    gulp.src([
       ./jspocket/scripts/navigation.js,
       // the rest of your files in your order
    ]) 
    .pipe(concat('jspocket.min.js'))  
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

then run `gulp minify-js`

Comment: What will be the output? Still, if I minify all the script files into one files, then $.getScript wont work.

Comment: @Incredible the output is the content of the files array minified

Comment: Does it minifi all the /script files into one file? If so then I suppose I will need one version of `jspocket.js` file in order to import files for non-minified framework and the other one for minified framework, am I right?

Comment: @Incredible Right, you can create none minified version using gulp too, basically what you are doing in `jspocket` gulp can do it for you or any other build system